# How to use mailmerge macro from excel to word with a click of a button in the excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to create a code which will be executed with a click of a button in the excel sheet and will ask me for an input of a cell value in excel which will then take all the data from that cell's row and insert it accordingly in the word template where the mail merge tags are.
for example :
**I have data like this in my excel sheet :**

> **ID(A1), Name(B1), Last Name(C1), Country(D1), Date(E1)**
>   378232625(A2), John(B2), Smith(C2), United States(D2), 29/02/2020(E2)
>   322783145(A3), Joshua(B3), Brand(C3), United States(D3), 27/02/2020(E3)

I want to have a button which will ask for an ID input and will then take all the other info of that person and place it in the word template in the correct place.

**For example:**

When a user runs the code it will pop up an input box and it will ask him to type an ID,
for example: 322783145
it will then check where the ID is placed(which row in A column) in the excel sheet which is A3 for this example and will pull the rest of this person's information into the word template I have created beforehand.(ID, Name, Last Name, Country and Date).

Later on I want to be able to automatically save it to pdf as well with the same button but first I want this to work.

**Thanks in advance :D**

Comment: Your post needs some more details for people to understand what you are trying to do and what code you need help with. Can you provide example content and more details about expected behavior?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I have edited my post with more detail, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this *with the question as originally posted* - simply use a SKIPIF field coded as:

```
{SKIPIF{MERGEFIELD ID}<> {FILLIN "Which ID do you want?" \o}}
```

or:

```
{SKIPIF«ID»<> {FILLIN "Which ID do you want?" \o}}
```

where 'ID' is the name of the data field in Excel you want to the merge to process.

With that, only the record containing that ID will be processed. No VBA required.

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.

**I see that you've added two new requirements, viz:**

- the mailmerge to be run from a button in Excel; and
- for it "to be able to automatically save it to pdf as well".

You really shouldn't move the goal posts this way. Nor should you ask ask multiple distinct questions in the same thread. For code to run a merge from Excel (and send the output to PDF), see *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html. Of course, once you get into using a macro such as this, you will need to add the logic for the ID selection to that code. Ask in a *separate thread* if you can't figure that out.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what it does?
lets say I have an excel sheet of ID's,names,and addresses(A1,A2,A3)  
I want to be able to input the ID in my word template(via input box)and it will take the name and the address of this particular person and put it in the word template using mail merge.
is your way of doing it fits the description?
Thanks alot btw :)

Comment: I edited my post to be more precise to my needs, thanks alot btw

Comment: may I also how do I implement it into my word template?
I know I have to edit it via Ctrl-F9 but I dont know where exactly to put this code.
kinda new to advanced excel stuff.

Comment: Well, it would have done, per your original question, but you have now entirely changed the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have used the code you recommended and it works great, could you help me adjust it so it will only save the last row that has values to pdf and not save all the rows to pdfs?

Comment: As I said, start a new thread with that question, showing us the actual code you're now using and what part of it you're having trouble with.